# Drawing rectangles from center of given coordinate

Tags: java, netbeans

I made a program where user enters number of rectangles to be drawn and coordinates at which the rectangles are drawn. My rectangles are currently drawn like this:

[image: link]

and I want to achieve this:

[image: link]

This is the code I use to draw the rectangles:

```
int povecaj_kvadrat=0;

    for(int x=0;x<broj_kvadrata;x++) {
        Rectangle2D.Float kvadrat=new Rectangle2D.Float(brojevi_koordinate[0],brojevi_koordinate[1],50+povecaj_kvadrat,50+povecaj_kvadrat);
        ploca.draw((kvadrat));
        povecaj_kvadrat=povecaj_kvadrat+15;
    }

      }
```

How do I set the coordinates of the rectangles so that they are drawn like in the second image?

Comment: Take a look at how `Rectangle2D.Float` is constructed. The first two parameters are not rectangle centre, but upper-left point. And in the loop you have this point is fixed and doesn't change

Answer (score 0):

You will have to take into account the additional size of each `Rectangle`, along with its position within the loop to compute the correct coordinates of each rectangle.

The additional size has been moved as a variable (`diffSize`), so that your loop can use its value.

The difference in coordinates between two iterations will be half this diff size, multiplied by the inverse of the position in the loop, because the lower the increment (x) and the `Rectangle` size, the bigger the coordinates .

```
        int gap = 0;
        int maxNumber = 3;
        int diffSize = 20;

        int[] coordinates = { 10, 10 };

        for (int x = 0; x <= maxNumber; x++) {
            Rectangle2D.Float rectangle = new Rectangle2D.Float(
                    coordinates[0] + ((diffSize / 2) * (maxNumber - x)),
                    coordinates[1] + ((diffSize / 2) * (maxNumber - x)),
                    50 + gap, 50 + gap);
            g2d.draw((rectangle));
            gap = gap + diffSize;
        }
```

Note that I am unsure of the correct behaviour if `diffSize` is odd (because `(diffSize / 2)` will be rounded down to the nearest `int` value), so I would keep an even value for `diffSize`.